# Implementation of member function: sorting Algorithms

Tags: c++, sorting, implementation

Please note this is not Homework:
I'm trying to implement the below functions and make sense of it all. the codes are copied from my textbook & put together. there are other .h and .cpp files that the functions will work together to produce the output. 
My question is: are my implementation logically correct? though I copied everything directly from the book it can't compile. The main.cpp and list.h & were taken from the book just like that, my own work here is trying to implement the sorts functions. It can't compile what is needed? suggestion? idea,       critics? thank you

```
 #ifndef SORTLIST_H
#define SORTLIST_H
#include "LIST.H"
#include "KEY.H"
#include "RECORD.H"


  template <class Record>
  class Sortable_list: public List<Record> {
  public:
    void insertion_sort(ItemType theArray[], int n) // todo: implement insertion sort
    {
    for (int unsorted = 1; unsorted < n; unsorted++)
    {
        ItemType nextItem = theArray[unsorted];
        int loc = unsorted;
        while ((loc> 0)&& (theArray[loc - 1] > nextItem))
        {
            theArray[loc] = theArray[loc - 1];
        }
        theArray[loc] = nextItem;
        loc--;
    }
}

void selection_sort(ItemType the Arrray[], int n) // todo: implement selection sort

{
    for(int last = n-1; last >1; last--)
    {
        int largest = findIndexofLargest(theArray, last+1);
        std::swap(theArray[largest], theArray[last]);
    }
}
int findIndexofLargest(const ItemType theArray[], int size)
{
    int indexSoFar = 0 ; //index of largest entry found so far
    for (int currentIndex = 1; currentIndex <size; currentIndex++)
    {
        if (theArray[currentIndex] > theArray[indexSoFar])
            indexSoFar = currentIndex;
    }
    return indexSoFar;
}



void quick_sort(ItemType the Array [], int first, int last)  // todo; implement quick sort
{
        if(last - first + 1 <MAX_LIST)
        {
    insertionSort(theArray, first, last);
}
else

{
    //create subarray s1 & s2

    int pivotIndex = partition(theArray, first, last);

    //sort subarrays s1 & s2

    quick_sort(theArray, first, pivotIndex - 1);

    quick_sort(theArray, pivotIndex + 1, last);

    }
}


void bubble_sort(ItemType theArray[], int n) // todo; implement bubble sort

{
    bool sorted = false;  //false when swap occur

    int pass = 1;

    while (!sorted && (pass < n))
    {
        sorted = true; //assume sorted

        for (int index = 0; index < n - pass; index++)

        {
            int nextIndex = index + 1;

            if (theArray[index] > theArray[nextIndex])

            {

                //exchange entry

                std::swap(theArray[index], theArray[nextIndex]);

                sorted = false;
            }
        }

        pass++;

    }
}

void merge(ItemType theArray[], int first, int mid, int last) // starting merge sort

{
    ItemType tempArray[MAX_LIST]; //temporary array

    int first1= first;

    int last1 = mid;

    int first2 = mid+1;

    int last2 = last;

    int index = first1; // next available in tempArray

    while ((first1 <= last1) && (first2 <= last2))

    {
        if (theArray[first1] <= theArray[first2])

        {
            tempArray[index] = theArray[first1]);

            first1++;
        }

        else

        {
            tempArray[index] = theArray[first2];

            first2++;
        }

        index++;
    }

    while (first1 <= last1) // finish the first subarray if necessary

    {
        tempArray[index] = theArray[first1;

        first++;

        index++;
    }
    //finish the second subArray

    while (first2 <= last2)

    {
        tempArray[index] = theArray[first2];

        first2++;

        index++;
    }

    for (index = first; index <= last; index++)

        theArray[index] = tempArray[index];
}

void merge_sort(ItemType theArray[], int first, int last) // todo; implement merge sort

{
    if (first < last)

    {
        //sort each half

        int mid = first + (last - first) / 2; //index of midpoint

        // sort left half

        merge_sort(theArray, first, mid);

        //sort right half

        merge_sort(theArray, mid + 1, last);

        //merge the two halves

        merge_sort(theArray, first, mid, last);
    }
}




   private:


// add private member functions if needed

};


#endif

//Main.cpp is the test driver to test the Sortlist class. 
//It contains user interface, filling the list with random integers, 
//calling Sortlist sorting functions and calculate the CPU time, 
//the number of comparison of keys, and the number of assignments of 
 //list entries during the sorting list.

    #include "stdafx.h"

    #include "RANDOM.H"

   #include "TIMER.H"

   #include "SORTLIST.H"   // SORTABLE LIST SPECIFICATION


   #include <iostream>


   using namespace std;

  void write_entry(Record &c)

  {

  cout << ((Key) c).the_key() << " ";

  }

    void help()

  {

  cout << "User options are:\n"

    << "[H]elp  [Q]uit  (re)[F]ill list \n"

    << "write [D]ata  write sorted [O]utput \n"

    << "[0] insertion sort \n"

    << "[1] selection sort \n"

    << "[2] shell sort     \n"

    << "[3] quick sort\n"

    << "[4] heap sort\n"

    << "[5] bubble sort \n"

    << "[6] merge sort \n"
    << endl;
 }

  void intro()

  {

 cout << "Testing program for sorting methods for a contiguous list."

    << endl;

 help ();

 }

 void main()

 {

 List<Record> s; List<Record> t = s;  //  help out an old compiler

 intro();

 int n;

 Random dice;

 bool report;

 Record target;

 Sortable_list<Record> the_list;

 Sortable_list<Record> copy_list;

 char command = ' ';

  while (command != 'q' && command != 'Q') {

    cout << "Enter a command of H, Q, F, O, D, "

       << "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6: " 

       << flush;

    cin  >> command;

    switch (command) {

     case 'h': case 'H':

       help();

     break;

     case 'd': case 'D':

        cout << "\nUnsorted list \n";

        the_list.traverse(write_entry);

        cout << endl;

     break;

     case 'o': case 'O':

        cout << "\nLast sorted list \n";

        copy_list.traverse(write_entry);

        cout << endl;

     break;

     case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': case '6': 
     {
        copy_list = the_list;

        Key::comparisons = 0;

        Key::assignments = 0;

        Timer clock;

        switch (command) {

          case '0': 

            cout << "Insertion Sort ";

          copy_list.insertion_sort();

        break;

          case '1': 

          cout << "Selection Sort ";

          copy_list.selection_sort();
        break;

          case '2': 

        cout << "    Shell Sort ";

          copy_list.shell_sort();

        break;

          case '3': 

          cout << "    Quick Sort ";

          copy_list.quick_sort();

        break;

         case '4': 

          cout << "     Heap Sort ";

          copy_list.heap_sort();

       break;

          case '5': 

          cout << "     Bubble Sort ";

          copy_list.bubble_sort();

        break;
          case '6': 

          cout << "     Merge Sort ";

          copy_list.merge_sort();

        break;

       }

       cout << "Time: " << clock.elapsed_time() << " seconds.\n"

            << "Comparisons: " << Key::comparisons << "\n"

            << "Assignments: " << Key::assignments

            << endl <<endl;
     }

     break;

     case 'f': case 'F':

       the_list.clear();

       cout << "How many list entries would you like? "

            << flush;

       cin  >> n;

       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

          target = dice.random_integer(0, 10 * n);

          the_list.insert(i, target, report);

          if (report == false) {

             cout << "Available list space filled up at " << i 

                  << " entries." << endl;
             break;

          }

          if (report != true) i--;
       }

     break;

   }  // end of outer switch statement

  }     // end of outer while statement


 }
```

And this is List.h is the template based array-based implementation of List class

```
const int MAX_LIST=10000;

template <class T>

class List

    {

  public:

List();  //default constructor. Create an empty list.

bool isEmpty() const;  // test if the list is empty

bool isFull() const;  // test if the list is full

int getLength() const; // get the length of the list

void insert(int index, const T& newItem, bool& success);

//Insert the newItem into the list at position index. NOTE: 0<=index<=getlength()

void remove(int index, bool& success);

//Remove an item from the list at position index. NOTE: 0<=index<=getlength()

void retrieve(int index, T& dataItem, bool& success) const;

// Retrieve a list item by position index. NOTE: 0<=index<=getlength()

void traverse (void(*visit)(T &));

//Traverse all items in the list from the beginning to the end

void clear(); // Remove all items from the list.

   protected:

T items[MAX_LIST];

int size; // number of items in the list
    };

    template <class T>

   List<T>::List()
   {
size=0;
  }

  template <class T>

bool List<T>::isEmpty() const

   {
return (size==0);
  }

  template <class T>

bool List<T>::isFull() const

  {
return (size >= MAX_LIST);
  }


  template <class T>

  int List<T>::getLength() const

  {
return size;

}

  template <class T>

  void List<T>::clear()

  {

size=0;

  }
```

Comment: For what it's worth, searching Google for "C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header" yields a lot of useful-looking results, some of which are on StackOverflow.

Comment: `void quick_sort(ItemType the Array [], int first, int last)  // todo; implement quick sort
{
    insertionSort(theArray, first, last);
}
else` Where is the `if` - `then` ?

Comment: forgot that: just edited if(last - first + 1 < MAX_LIST)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are compiling using VC++ with precompiled headers turned on. In that case, the compiler will ignore anything you have in your translation unit it find a line reading

```
#include <stdafx.h>
```

Everything preceding this line will be replaced by the content of the precompiled header. I haven't really looked at anything else in your file because the above error needs to be fixed before you get sensible error messages for your actual code.

Comment: Yeah I'm using VC++, U mean I should add #include <stdafx.h> in my header file? little bit confused here